# AI’s reflection of the Collective Unconscious

Tags: artificial-intelligence, idealism, jung

I’m very new to philosophy, only having read some Emerson and currently loving Kierkegaard, so I apologize in advance if this isn’t the right place to ask this or if it’s a very rudimentary question.

My understanding of ChatGPT, and any reinforcement learned language models for that matter, is that it’s trained upon a *ton* of human speech and writing. It then notices statistical patterns and responds to test data accordingly. My question therefore emerges: since it learns and responds as an aggregate of many, many humans, are the patterns it detects, especially those of emotion, not just a reflection of the collective unconscious, of all our shared concepts which we unknowingly expressed similarly? I’ve been taught that term as Jung’s collective unconscious, but I guess it’s more of a collective conscious, as it’s directly expressed thoughts which are commonly aggregated between us to decide its next word. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Insofar as I'm concerned, I don't want to interact with ChatGPT at the moment. I've seen some secondhand sample texts and they're amazing literary works if you could call it that, but what does it all mean? I repeat, what does it all mean?

Comment: Yes, it reflects patterns, not even unconscious. Start with biases, racism and other unsavory trends it finds in "a ton of human speech and writing"...

Comment: @AgentSmith -- One might say current outputs from language transformers are artifacts of the collective extended mind. If we consider that language in general is such an artifact, yet also that it lives on within us, perhaps much of thought itself is something of a collective artifact. Hence, the difference between outputs of ChatGPT, and outputs of human commenters here on SE, may be one of degree -- that is, degree of separation between soul and symbol.

Comment: Maybe [archetypes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jungian_archetypes#Examples) are already defined as features in ChatGPT's design.

Comment: @Michael, possible. I haven't had the time, nor do I desire, to converse with ChatGPT. It's a neat hypothesis.